# Invisible Character Encoding

Tags: javascript, unicode, invisible

Could you use unicode whitespace characters to encode information in browser pages?

I'm thinking about characters that display as whitespace, but are encoded by a different Unicode character? It seems like this could be used to identify a page displayed by a user without making it obvious (i.e., for copyright or tracking purposes).

Are there guides to doing this out there already?

Comment: Yes. But the usecases are definetly to broad. And asking for "guides" is off-topic. Please read [ask] carefully again

Comment: https://330k.github.io/misc_tools/unicode_steganography.html